# How to calculate the distance between two points on a circle in degrees

Tags: geometry

I've been trying to figure this out for several hours now and am having trouble finding the right solution.

Given two points on a circle and the radius of the circle I need to calculate the distance in degrees between the two points on the circle. Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

In this picture I have a point at (-12.2,12.7) which represents the center of the circle. I know the radius of the circle (5.344) and I have two points on the circle. One at (-12.4,7.4) and another at (-17, 13.7). I need to get the length of the arc in degrees. I know if I have the center angle I can calculate the arc length, but I can't find anything about how to determine the center angle without already knowing the arc length.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT

Updating the image to use real values

Comment: Hint: unit circle.

Comment: Suppose the angle is $\theta$. Looking at the $y$-coordinate, you have $\cos\theta=0.5$. So $\theta=60^o$.

Comment: @almagest I don't understand, you're doing the inverse cosine of y? That will only work if my scale is between 0 and 1 right? I need a formula that I can use for values larger than one.

Comment: I'm not convinced that $ \ (0.7, \ 0.5) \ $ is one unit away from the origin.  Are all of your coordinates correct?

Comment: @omatase Call $C$ the centre of the circle, $P$ the point $(.7,.5)$ and $Q$ the point $(0,0.5)$. Then $CPQ$ is a right-angled triangle. Do you remember basic trigonometry. The cosine of $\angle POQ$ is adjacent/hypotenuse = $OQ/OP=0.5/1$.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes, either the point is $(0.8660,0.5)$ or $(0.7,0.7141)$ or something entirely different!

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I had to come up with a hypothetical value for those points because I don't currently have real-world values to plug in. I'm implementing this for code in a game so the game engine will provide the values for x and y in realtime.

Comment: Related: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54114.html

Comment: @omatase Your new values make no sense either. The distance from $(-12.2,12.7)$ to $(-12.4,7.3$ is $5.404$ which roughly matches your radius. However the distance from $(-12.2,12.7)$ to $(17,13.7)$ is $29.217$. Also the placement of your points doesn't make sense. In the vertical direction the value $13.7$ is more than $12.7$ and less than $7.4$. Even with an inverted y-axis which some programming languages use, the order doesn't make sense. Please re-reread your diagram and clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @IanMiller the second point on the circle is actually supposed to be (-17,13.7) so I copied it in wrong. These are points on a circle and the center is (-12.2, 12.7)

Answer (score 3):

If the included angle is $\theta$ and the radius is $r$ then $$ s= r \theta$$

To find the included angle $\theta$ subtract the two orientation angles you get from an $\arctan(y/x)$ operation

$$ \theta = \arctan\left( \frac{y_2}{x_2} \right) -\arctan\left( \frac{y_1}{x_1} \right) $$

<sub>NOTES: You might need to use the `ATAN2(dy,dx)` function to resolve angles in all the quadrants</sub>

Comment: so given two points (0,5) and (5,0) θ would be 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Since both points are in the first quadrant $\arctan \left( \frac{5}{0} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arctan \left( \frac{0}{5} \right) = 0$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to take into account your change of question**

**(Actually - ignoring your diagram and using my own)**

[image]

Applying dot product of the two vectors you get:

$$\cos\theta=\frac{(x_1-x_c)(x_2-x_c)+(y_1-y_c)(y_2-y_c)}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_c)^2+(y_1-y_c)^2}\times\sqrt{(x_2-x_c)^2+(y_2-y_c)^2}}$$

so that

$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(x_1-x_c)(x_2-x_c)+(y_1-y_c)(y_2-y_c)}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_c)^2+(y_1-y_c)^2}\times\sqrt{(x_2-x_c)^2+(y_2-y_c)^2}}\right)$$

Note: The bottoms of these fraction is just the radius times radius of your circle. However your shapes so far have not been circles so this is a general formula that will give you the angle between any two random points compared to a center point.

Comment: Cosine in the fourth quadrant is the same as cosine in the first...

Comment: If I use this method plugging in some generic numbers (0,5) and (5,0) I get 90 degrees which is correct, but when I plug in the numbers in my image (-12.4, 17) and (7.4, 13.7) I get some weird results 180. - 308.728 I. See here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+cosine+of+((-12.4*17)+%2B+(7.4*13.7)). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Whats wrong?" - you changed the question. Before you had a radius of one. I'll update my answer to match your new version of the question.

Comment: @DJohnM Thanks. Removed unnecessary (and wrong) statement about quadrants.

Comment: Aaaaah! Now I see why there were so many problems with my original image. It was just supposed to be an example of a possible set of numbers, it wasn't ever supposed to mean that the radius will always be 1.  In the real world when I use this equation to solve the problem, although the radius will be known, it will not always be the same between circles (same with the other points).

Comment: @IanMiller So, to clarify, if I *am* using a perfect circle I can use r^2 for the denominator on the two fractions?

Comment: Yes. In a perfect circle case the denominator will be $r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram showing the center at $(0,0)$ is inconsistent with the other points in the diagram, and with the stated form of the problem.  So:

Edit:  *The edited question confirms the assumptions of this solution.*

Given **two points on a circle** and **the radius $R$**, first calculate the distance $D$ between the two given points, the chord between the two points:$$D=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2} $$

Half this length, $\frac D2$, along with the radius form one side and the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle. So, the angle at the centre, $\theta$ subtended by the **entire** chord, is given by:$$\theta=2\times \arcsin \left(\frac{D}{2R} \right)$$

A slightly more complex method is to use the Law of Cosines.  With $R$ given, and $D$ calculated:$$\cos({\theta)}=\frac{R^2+R^2-D^2}{2R^2}$$

Comment: It sounds like this will give me the center angle, but then how do I get the length of the arc?

Comment: @omatase You didn't ask for the length of the arc. You asked for the distance in degrees.

Comment: @IanMiller Sorry, I'm struggling to use the right terms here. To me there's no difference in meaning between "distance between two points on the circle" and "length of the arc". Degrees or radians or whatever is fine but degrees is what I understand the best.